# BPMN where to put end event for 3 different events in XOR gateway

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bizagi

I need help with this bpmn diagram drawing

There will be 3 senarios to this event,

1. customer report book is lost / damage
   -----then system will calculate the cost of the book and attach fee to customer account **then the process will be aborted**
2. customer return the book
   -----system will calculate the late penalty and attach fee to customer account **the process will be aborted**
3. customer did not return the book
   -----case will be escalated to manager, manager will then take even more steps, such as check if its student or staff. different action will be take for student and staff the process will end after a series of activity.

this is how it looks like now, i am not sure how to link them to the end event

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your diagramme is actually almost complete. Your process has three possible endings. So, you should also have three different end events: one attached to the last task of each scenario. That means you do not need that closing exclusive gateway on the right-hand side of your diagramme. You could add the three titles that you have used in your post to label the scenarios to also label the end events.

By the way, "aborted" is not a term in BPMN. Maybe you meant [terminated](https://camunda.com/bpmn/reference/#events-termination) or [canceled](https://camunda.com/bpmn/reference/#events-cancel)? In both cases, I would be surprised because both types of end events would only make sense when you have multiple process instances running in parallel with some kind of dependency between them. Based on your diagramme, that would mean that someone is running two parallel but separate checks whether a book has been returned (could be the same book or different books). If one of those two checks yields that a book has been lost or returned, both process instances of checking a book's return status will be immediately stopped (assuming the other check did not already finish). I suppose you do not want that. From the business case that you are describing, a normal end event would be the way to go.